# Using certificates in urllib3

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

I'm a Python newbie. I'm using urllib3 to talk to an api. The reason I'm using this and not requests is that I'd like to host my app on GAE. My app uses certicates. When I post data, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cert_reqs'
```

How can I include certs in my urlopen call? A snippet of code follows

```
CA_CERTS = ('client-2048.crt', 'client-2048.key')

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.urlopen('POST', url, body=payload, headers={'X-Application': '???', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, cert_reqs='REQUIRED', ca_certs=CA_CERTS)
print r.status, r.data
```

Comment: Unless you are using sockets (billing enabled) any outbound request will use urlfetch.

Comment: @TimHoffman: I'm confused. I have another app running on a nonbilled account that uses urllib3 and urlopen()

Comment: Yes but underneath it is calling urlfetch, so your ultimately limited to what functionality urlfetch provides.

Comment: Connection pools aren't very useful on appengine for any concurrency you should look at async requests

Answer (score 10):

You can drop down to the [HTTPSConnectionPool](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pools.html#urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool) level which you may do directly:

```
from urllib3.connectionpool import HTTPSConnectionPool
conn = HTTPSConnectionPool('httpbin.org', ca_certs='/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem', cert_reqs='REQUIRED')
```

Or, more simply or via the `connection_from_url()` helper function:

```
conn = urllib3.connection_from_url('https://httpbin.org', ca_certs='/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem', cert_reqs='REQUIRED')
```

Note that `ca_certs` is the file name of a certificate bundle used to validate the remote server's certificate. Use `cert_file` and `key_file` to present your client certificate to the remote server:

```
conn = urllib3.connection_from_url('https://httpbin.org', cert_file='client-2048.crt', key_file='client-2048.key', ca_certs='/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem', cert_reqs='REQUIRED')
```

Then issue your request:

```
response = conn.request('POST', 'https://httpbin.org/post', fields={'field1':1234, 'field2':'blah'})
>>> print response.data
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "field1": "1234",
    "field2": "blah"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "220",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=048b02ad15274fc485c2cb2b6a280034",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "X-Request-Id": "92fbc1da-d83e-439c-9468-65d27492664f"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "220.233.14.203",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the `cert_reqs='REQUIRED'` and `ca_certs=CA_CERTS` args to the `PoolManager()` instantiation directly.

So the original example can be changed to this:

```py
CA_CERTS = ('client-2048.crt', 'client-2048.key')

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='REQUIRED', ca_certs=CA_CERTS)

r = http.urlopen('POST', url, body=payload, headers={'X-Application': '???', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
print r.status, r.data
```

Answer (score 0):

**Passing `User-Agent` header seemed to help** in my case, on top of the other answers.

Not sure if this is a common behaviour, but my server would return `403 - Access denied` error when performing a HTTPS request using self-signed certificates and without `User-Agent`.

When ignoring certificates (ie. using an empty `ssl.SSLContext`) the `User-Agent` header wasn't required and the request would succeed. Only when [passing a self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23957365/3508719) using the `ca_certs` parameter, I needed to include the `User-Agent`

```py
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='REQUIRED', ca_certs='/path/to/cacert.pem')
r = http.urlopen('GET', url, headers={'User-Agent': 'myapp/v0.1.0'})
print(r.data)
```

I cannot find any source indicating why `User-Agent` may be required when using a self-signed certificate. Any clarification on that point most welcome.

Read more about `User-Agent` header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).